# Stop one thread and start the other?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I am having trouble stopping one thread and starting another one. I have created two threads. One of them is first run from the main method. It then takes user input and if the desired input is provided, thread one (sound) is supposed to stop and start thread two (sound2). From the code below, thread two does start playing after the correct input is provided during thread one. But thread one does not stop. I can hear audio files from both thread one and thread two playing. Please help.

```
public class crytask {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable sound = new sound();
    final Thread soundthread = new Thread(sound);

    soundthread.start();
    int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        if (a==12)
        soundthread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("this thread is cancelled");

    Runnable sound2 = new sound2();
    final Thread soundthread2 = new Thread(sound2);
    soundthread2.start();
    int count2 = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter");
    Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int b = reader2.nextInt();
    if (b==12)
    soundthread2.interrupt();

}}


class sound implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {     
    try {       
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream =       AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/Con1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Cancelled 1!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class sound2 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {     
    try {       
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/Con1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream2);
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Cancelled 2!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you have: `if (a==12)` before your interrupt, does `a == 12` return true?

Comment: yes. i entered 12 and it seems to move forward to sound2 but sound1 continues to play the sound.

Comment: just because you moved on does not mean that was true, the only bit of code affected by that if statement is `soundthread.interrupt()`

Comment: How do you know thread one does not stop?

Comment: @immibis because I can still hear the sound that is played from thread one.

Comment: Interrupting the thread will not stop playback. You'll notice that the `start()` method of your `Clip` returns immediately - it's not a blocking call. This should suggest to you that the processing/playback is taking place somewhere else, *not* on the thread you're interrupting.

Comment: @rookie Why do you think the thread is playing the sound? The thread started the sound, but it's not the thread that keeps it playing. (In fact you probably didn't need a thread to start the sound with).

Answer (score 4):

Try stopping the clip when the thread is interrupted, adding `clip.close()` to the catch clause that catches the interruptedException, like this:

```
class sound implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Clip clip = null; // take the declaration of the clip variable out of the try - catch
        try {       
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream =
                   AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/Con1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            clip.stop(); // <--- ADD THIS LINE
            System.out.println("Cancelled 1!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. The `Clip` class does not block on a call to `start()`, it returns immediately - it's not going to require the calling Thread to continue existing/executing for playback to occur. Thus the `Clip` needs to be manually stopped when you want playback to cease.